# Microsoft Azure Operations are Missing from RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

What happened to the

- 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/backupJobsExport/operationResults/read'
- 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/backupManagementMetaData/read'

operations in Azure? They exist in this documentation...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/recoveryservices/operations%20vaults/list

but not in this documentation...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations

and I cannot find them in the output of the Get-AzureRmProviderOperation powershell command.

Were the operations renamed or have the services they grant access to no longer support those operations?

Comment: probably worth raising on github, i can confirm those are gone, maybe renamed, this looks pretty close: `Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/backupJobs/operationResults/read`, not sure about the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 2 operations were definitely removed as part of following commit on github.
I will try to find out about 2nd part of this question ..ie. what is the replacement or change

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/49a405a66cd91e29f9f07dfe0e057d9fdee7ac50?diff=split

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both these operations are not required for RBAC to run and hence they were removed from the ‘resource-provider-operations’ URL. The Microsoft engineer said that they will be removed from the other document as well to keep the documentation consistent.